# SQL query to transform this data dimension

Tags: sql, reporting

Is there any simple SQL query to convert this below data

> Date   - Item  - cost
>   10/31/2009 - a - 1
>   10/31/2009 - b - 2
>   10/31/2009 - c - 3
>   10/31/2009 - d - 4
>
> 11/30/2009 - a - 5
>   11/30/2009 - b - 6
>   11/30/2009 - c - 7
>   11/30/2009 - d - 8

Into below report format without any application logic/store procedure/reporting tool?

> Item - 10/31/2009 -  11/30/2009
>   a -  1      - 5
>   b -  2      - 6
>   c -  3      - 7
>   d -      4      - 8

Sorry, couldn't come up with a better title..

Comment: Is 11/31/2009 in the sample input intentional? Does the report need to cater for only two dates or is this variable? What do you need done if one of the items is not present on one of the dates?

Comment: Changed 11/31/2009 to 11/30/2009, that was Cltr + CV error :)
The dates change, next time there will be one more date 12/31/2009.. basically it's a report what I want to see, how the cost of an item changes across months..

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
  item,
  MAX(CASE WHEN dt = CAST('2009-10-31' AS DATE) THEN cost END) AS oct2009_cost,
  MAX(CASE WHEN dt = CAST('2009-11-30' AS DATE) THEN cost END) AS nov2009_cost,
  MAX(CASE WHEN dt = CAST('2009-12-31' AS DATE) THEN cost END) AS dec2009_cost
FROM items
GROUP BY
  item;
```

Comment: The date's are not static. I can't hard-code dates. The dates should come the table itself. Any other ideas? Appreciate you help.

Comment: Do you always know how many dates you will need? If not, you will need to generate the query dynamically. What criteria do you apply to find out such dates (eg. the 5 latest end of month dates for which tehre is data)?

Comment: I'm trying to SQL pivot and do this, not there yet. But almost there. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410.aspx